# spring cloud config client side backup

Tags: spring-cloud

Trying to address the scenario where client is unable to reach config server for whatever reason.
Any way to implement "last known good state" ?
I suppose it needs to be  local_disk/remote_storage  based backup option to work with ephemeral/non_ephemeral client instances.

Any other options ?

Comment: Can you tell me more about your use case? At what point in the lifecycle of a client are you talking about?

Comment: Just during the init/start or re-start of a client instance.

As part of start, client reaches out to config service to get the current config. If config service is not available (for whatever reason), how can the client  continue ? Does it keep retrying till the config is available, or it starts based on the "last known good state" while retrying in parallel.

Comment: There is a retry mechanism. There is no facility to store the config retrieved from config server data as a backup. If the config server can't reach the git/svn server, it will still serve up the data it has cloned already.